# Comparison method of objects

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write the **comparison method** between two classes and I don't know how. I wrote this, and I catch numbers but I can't compare them.

```
pi.avg_sen1()
cm1=pi.avg_ghad1()

heavy1=pi.avg_vazn1()
pu.avg_sen2()
cm2=pu.avg_ghad2()
heavy2=pu.avg_vazn2()


if cm1 > cm2:
   print('A')
elif cm1 < cm2:
   print('B')
elif cm1 == cm2:
   if heavy1 < heavy2:
      print("A")
   elif heavy1 > heavy2:
      print("B")
   elif heavy1 == heavy2:
      print("same")
```

Comment: What is your error? What is the expected result and what is the current one?
Your code seems fine.

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: It sounds like both args to a '>' comparison are NoneType. That means either cm1 and cm2 are NoneType, or perhaps heavy1 and heavy2 are. Try printing out the value of all four variables just before the first 'if' and it will probably become obvious.

Comment: @saeedkhalilian please edit your original post to add the error message and any other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

## First approach

If you want to make a class, and set a comparsion method for this class, then you need to do it as follows:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number
  
  def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, A):
      raise NotImplementedError
    else:
      return self.number == other.number

  def __gt__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, A):
      raise NotImplementedError
    else:
      return self.number > other.number

  def __lt__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, A):
      raise NotImplementedError
    else:
      return self.number < other.number
```

You need to use methods like `__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__le__`, `__ge__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`. See: [PEP 207 -- Rich Comparisons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/).

## Explicit

You can also dynamically add a comparsion method for a class that you have imported. Look at this:

```
from foo import Bar

def eq_bars(self, other):
  if not isinstance(other, Bar):
    raise NotImplementedError
  else:
    return self.some_val = other.some_val

Bar.__eq__ = eq_bars
```